# Read-only not working primeng inputNumber

Tags: angular, input, primeng

I want to make primeng InputNumber read-only. 
I followed the documentation and I added [readonly]="true" to my input but unfortunately it does nothing, I can still edit my input.

Documentation:

http://primefaces.org/primeng/inputnumber

[image]

This is my code:

[image]

I already tried writing "readOnly" instead of "readonly" but still not working.

Comment: it seems readonly is not working indeed. try adding `disabled` instead

Comment: Mh, thank you. I don't want the grey effect though, should I change the css either for achiving the same effect as read-only?

Comment: Seems to work fine at least in Chrome: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-inputnumber-demo-inspj3?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Which primeng version are you using?
This should have been fixed since 13.0.0 according to [changelog](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1300-2021-11-24)